# How to add a fixed header for all screens in react-native-navigation v2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I would like to know if it's possible to add a fixed header to all screens in react-native-navigation v2. Something like this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flex: 0.3}}>
        <Text>Fixed Banner</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 0.7}}>
        Navigation.setRoot({
            root: {
                bottomTabs: {
                    id: 'BottomTabsId',
                    children: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'SignIn',
                            options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    text: 'Sign In',
                                    icon: require('./signin.png')
                                 }
                             }
                        },
                   },
                   ...
              ],
          }
    </View>
</View>
```

Whenever I switch tabs to another screen, ideally I would like to see the same banner always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the banner in an [Overlay](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/top-level-api?id=showoverlaylayout-).